# Infinispan Jgroups Leave Message

Tags: java, cluster-computing, infinispan, jgroups, wildfly-9

I want to ask if with infinispan there is the possibility for each cluster node to send a leave message.

In my use-case, each node in the cluster is represented by a web application (a single war). So inside my application server there are as many cluster nodes as the number of webapplication deployed.

The problem occurs when a web application is undeployed. The cluster view list doesn t realize that a node leaved the cluster and when i re-deploy the application again the cluster adds the new node without deleting the previous one. The result is that the cluster view grows every time i deploy an application.

Is there the way to send a "leave message" every time an application is undeployed?

I used this snippet code to force jgroups to send new configuration, but doing this way the situation gets really instable.

```
        Transport   tp;
        tp=cacheManager.getCache(SessionConstants.CACHE_MANAGER_GLOBAL_JNDI_NAME).getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getTransport();
        Channel ch=((JGroupsTransport)tp).getChannel();

        View view=ch.getView();
        org.jgroups.Address localAddr=ch.getAddress();
        org.jgroups.Address coord=view.getMembersRaw()[0];

        int index = view.getMembers().indexOf(localAddr);


        if(cacheManager.getTransport().getMembers().size() == 1) {
              logger.error("Coordinator cannot change as view only has a single member");
            return;
        }

        List<org.jgroups.Address> mbrs=new ArrayList<>(view.getMembers());
        long new_id=view.getViewId().getId() + 1;

        org.jgroups.Address tmp_coord=mbrs.remove(index);
        //mbrs.add(tmp_coord);
        View new_view=new View(mbrs.get(0), new_id, mbrs);
        GMS gms=(GMS)ch.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(GMS.class);
        gms.castViewChange(new_view, null, mbrs);
```

Using this code, the cluster is notified when a node leaves the cluster but i loose some data.

So i hope infinispan provides some api to handle this situation.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with calling {{cacheManager.stop()}}? That closes the JGroups channel and leaves cluster gracefully, both on Infinispan and JGroups side.

Comment: @Flavius, might not be a good idea if the cache manager is bound to JNDI. See Paul's reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619271/infinispan-jgroups-crashes-after-war-deploying/38741204?noredirect=1#comment64857105_38741204).